# Wordpress pages with the same slug

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, dns, slug

I`m using Polylang to translate my pages.I have two pages,for example one is example.bg/blog ,and the other one should be examample.com/blog.Wordpress wont allow me to have two pages with the same slug.I have two domains ,as the .bg one is used for my BG version.
Can I achieve this changing .htacess file?
Or any other way?